# Merging two dataset - include unique rows

Tags: r, merge, sum, bioinformatics

I have a dataset as this:

```
Island,Individual,all1,all2
Santiago,CVW3,01,01
Santiago,CVW8,01,02
Santiago,CVW9,03,03
Santiago,CVW10,01,01
Santiago,CVW12,03,03
Santiago,CVW19,01,01
Santiago,CVW25,01,04
Santiago,CVW39,04,04
Santiago,CVW40,01,01
Santiago,CVW41,01,01
Fogo,CVW64,04,04
Fogo,CVW67,01,01
Fogo,CVW70,02,04
Fogo,CVW74,03,05
Fogo,CVW80,01,02
Fogo,CVW99,01,04
Fogo,CVW101,02,02
Fogo,CVW103,01,02
Fogo,CVW104,01,04
Fogo,CVW111,02,04
SaoNicolau,CVW81,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW87,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW92,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW124,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW125,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW133,01,01
SaoNicolau,CVW136,01,01
```

The data in all1 and all2 are factors.
I need to calculate the combined frequency of each of the factors in all1 and all2, both within each subset of Island and for the overall dataset.
So for Santiago and 01, the frequency would be: 12/20.

I have worked on splitting the dataset into island as such:

```
#Get data subset for Santiago:
stsplit = subset(locus, locus$Island == "Santiago")

allfr1st = count(stsplit, "all1")
allfr2st = count(stsplit, "all2")

#Rename headers:
names(allfr1st) = c("Allele", "Freq")
names(allfr2st) = c("Allele", "Freq")
```

This gives me:
    allfr1st:

```
Allele,Freq
01,7
03,2
04,1


allfr2st:

Allele,Freq
01,5
02,1
03,2
04,2
```

Now I want to sum the frequencies of each allele for the two data frames, so I would get the below

```
Allele,Freq
01,12
02,1
03,4
04,3
```

`merge()` excludes allele 02, as it is not in both datasets.
How do I combine the two in the right way?

If there is (and there surely is) a more obvious way of getting what I want (the frequencies of 01, 02, 03 etc both overall and within islands), please feel free to give me advice on that as well.

Comment: If you're working with microsatellite data, have a look at `adegenet` package.

Comment: you can use `merge(all.x=T,all.y=T,...)`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, thank you for your advice. This is not ms data, but alleles from functional DNA. but I think that the adegenet package could do what I want - calculate expected heterozygosity. However, I have experimented with the adegenet package, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting my data accepted in R.

Comment: @Jason, thank you. This essentially gives me the same as `rbind()`, though sorted differently. What I want, is the data summed on Freq. So if 01 is in both datasets, I want the summed Freq. If 01 is not i both datasets, I still want it included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?
The script counts number of each "loci" and divides it by the number of all loci per location.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Island,Individual,all1,all2
                 Santiago,CVW3,01,01
                 Santiago,CVW8,01,02
                 Santiago,CVW9,03,03
                 Santiago,CVW10,01,01
                 Santiago,CVW12,03,03
                 Santiago,CVW19,01,01
                 Santiago,CVW25,01,04
                 Santiago,CVW39,04,04
                 Santiago,CVW40,01,01
                 Santiago,CVW41,01,01
                 Fogo,CVW64,04,04
                 Fogo,CVW67,01,01
                 Fogo,CVW70,02,04
                 Fogo,CVW74,03,05
                 Fogo,CVW80,01,02
                 Fogo,CVW99,01,04
                 Fogo,CVW101,02,02
                 Fogo,CVW103,01,02
                 Fogo,CVW104,01,04
                 Fogo,CVW111,02,04
                 SaoNicolau,CVW81,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW87,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW92,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW124,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW125,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW133,01,01
                 SaoNicolau,CVW136,01,01", header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
                 colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "character", "character"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

by(xy, xy$Island, FUN = function(x) {
  table(c(x$all1, x$all2))/length(c(x$all1, x$all2))
})

xy$Island:                  Fogo

  01   02   03   04   05 
0.30 0.30 0.05 0.30 0.05 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
xy$Island:                  Santiago

  01   02   03   04 
0.60 0.05 0.20 0.15 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
xy$Island:                  SaoNicolau

01 
 1
```